# Detecting specific function passed to function parameter of function template

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Consider the following template function which has a single template parameter:

```
typedef void (func_t)();

void defaultF() {}

template <func_t F = defaultF>
void foo() {
  F();
}
```

Now within `foo()` I want to determine if F is the default argument of `defaultF`.

Doing a direct address comparison<sup>1</sup>:

```
template <func_t F = defaultF>
void foo() {
    if (F == defaultF) {
        cout << "DefaultF";
    } else {
        cout << "Something else...";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Seems to work on the compilers I tried it on, but it is guaranteed to be a valid technique?

---

<sup>1</sup> At least I assume this is equivalent to a function address comparison: I wasn't able to actually write `&F` but I guess it decays anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is a function pointer comparison, and it does work.  You can’t write `&F` because the template parameter, like a regular function parameter, [decays to a pointer](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#8), so `F` is already a pointer (and a prvalue).